# Symfony2 uncaught exception inside Event Listener

Tags: symfony, exception, listener, uncaught-exception

I have a problem with throwing Symfony 2 exception inside event listner. When I do it I get Uncaught exception (onRequest method of listener). Is there any way to throw exception in listener that can be caught by Symfony.

I was trying to avoid this problem by changing the controller in case of an exception (onController method of listener). Target controller had just one line:

```
throw $this->createNotFoundException('Test');
```

The controller swap worked but it also resulted in uncaught exception error.

How to wrap a listener or swapped controller inside symfony exception catcher.

My listener:

```
namespace AppBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use AppBundle\Controller\HomeController;

class SessionListener {

    private $container;

    public function __construct($container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function onController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $controller=new HomeController();

        $replacementController= array($controller, 'notFoundAction');

        $event->setController($replacementController);
    }

    public function onRequest(Event $event) {
        $session = $this->container->get('session'); 
        $kernel = $this->container->get('kernel');

        throw new NotFoundHttpException('Test');
    }

}
```

My services.yml

```
services:
    app.session_listener:
        class: AppBundle\Listener\SessionListener
        arguments: [@service_container]    
        tags:
         - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onRequest }
         - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onController }
```

Comment: It might be that symfony calls a subrequest on exception (see `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\EventListener:50`) and if you're throwing an exception in the `onRequest` method this exception won't be handled properly by the default exception controller (`Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController:showAction`). If you want full control on exception handling I'd look into implementing your custom exception listener. If you just want to return something directly from `onRequest` you can use `$event->setResponse()` to stop propagation and return your response.

Comment: I have tried this before and it works but I was hoping to catch this exception with default Symfony exception handler. Also it would be nice to redirect controler that can use application container and all its features. The setResponse method is good enough in my case.

Answer (score 1):

probably with a try catch

```
public function onRequest(Event $event) {

 try{

  $session = $this->container->get('session'); 
  $kernel = $this->container->get('kernel');

 }catch(NotFoundHttpException ex){

  throw new NotFoundHttpException('Test');

 }




}
```

Comment: This is wrong, if there is no exception catching in onRequest method this will also result in uncought exception error. I am looking for a way to catch this exception by symfony default exception handler. @mickadoo comment is better but not quite there.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can return a 404 response instead of throwing an exception:

```
class SessionListener
{
    public function onRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $event->setResponse(new Response('Test', 404));
    }
}
```